# How to escape a period (.) in WCF Data Services QueryString

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Services service that exposes a set of [ICD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD) codes. The primary key for the underlying table and the data set that WCF provides access to is a `varchar` or `string` in C#.

The service works properly if I have a query like this:

```
http://somehost/someService.svc/IcdSet('001')
```

If, however, the ICD code happens to have a `.` in the identifier as many do, the service fails. Here's an example of one that won't work (IIS gives a 404 - Not Found response):

```
http://somehost/someService.svc/IcdSet('001.1')
```

So the question is **how can I escape the period or properly pass it to WCF Data Services**?  It must be interpreting it as a different type of filter condition.

**Note:** The code for the underlying class seems irrelevant to the question but I can provide it if needed.

**Edit**: My *guess* at the moment is that IIS is trying to find a file that ends with `.1')` which is then producing the 404 error. But how can I tell IIS that it shouldn't be looking for files as these are all data queries?

Comment: by any chance do you have the app pool set to classic? You should set it to integrated if so, that might fix your issue.

Comment: It's hosted on IIS 7 in integrated mode on a Win 2K8 Server. The problem is replicated in my Visual Studio environment as well.

Comment: have you tried url escaping the period?

Comment: Something like `.../IcdSet('001%2E1')`, where `%2E` is a `.` character doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx

Also might be of interest if you're using .Net 3.5 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5121